# OutupStream SSH empty

Tags: android, eclipse, ssh

I'm trying to show the execution result a command by SSH, and for that I'm using this code I found on internet:

```
public static String executeRemoteCommand(
                       String username,
                       String password,
                       String hostname,
                       int port) throws Exception {     

  JSch jsch = new JSch();
  Session session = jsch.getSession(username, hostname, 22);
  session.setPassword(password);

  // Avoid asking for key confirmation
  Properties prop = new Properties();
  prop.put("StrictHostKeyChecking", "no");
  session.setConfig(prop);

  session.connect();

  // SSH Channel
  ChannelExec channelssh = (ChannelExec) 
                           session.openChannel("exec");      
  ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
  channelssh.setOutputStream(baos);

  // Execute command
  channelssh.setCommand("ls");
  channelssh.connect();        
  channelssh.disconnect();

  return baos.toString();
}
```

The connection is done well, but it always returns the string is empty.

What do I do wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I think you forgot to run the command with a [`start()`](https://github.com/is/jsch/blob/b2ac6d9c95a688b22cbc3316ccf3315ba2fb6f86/src/com/jcraft/jsch/ChannelExec.java#L38) call.

Comment: The command is running, because I tried to put a command to shut down the computer, and the computer shuts down. But if I put a command that returns some text (ls for example), do not return any text.

Comment: Try setting the error stream `setErrStream` and check it for errors.

Answer (score 0):

The correct stream for reading is

```
InputStream inputStream = channelssh.getInputStream();
```

Then read it like :

```
BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream));
StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
String line;
while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
    stringBuilder.append(line);
    stringBuilder.append('\n');
}
```